# Can I limit the result of JPQL to just return one result?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I would like to do something like this (in Spring Data JPA) in a repository interface:

```
interface myRepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
    @Query("select a from A a where a.x = :x")
    A findFirstBySomeCondition(int x);
}
```

But I only need the first result. (Edited: The actual query condition is much complex so I would prefer to use @Query instead of findFirst or findTop...)

I don't want to use criteria api, because it's verbose.

I don't want to use the the native query cause I will have to compose the query string manually.

So, is there an solution left though, given the restricted requirement above?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: `findFirst` [works](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).  If your requirement is really as simple as you have posted, `A findFirstByX(int x)` will work without the `@Query` annotation.  Check the Spring Data JPA documentation I have linked to.

Comment: that is a vastly simplified example, so I would like to use `@Query` instead of `findFirst`.

Comment: Then you should improve your question.  The way it is posted right now is the exact use case described in the documentation so it comes across as a debugging problem instead of a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The results of query methods can be limited via the keywords first or top, which can be used interchangeably. An optional numeric value can be appended to top/first to specify the maximum result size to be returned.

```
interface myRepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
    @Query("select a from A a where a.x = :x")
    Page<A> findFirstBySomeCondition(@Param("x") int x,Pageable pageable);
}
```

Impletation Class:

```
Page<A> results = repository.findFirstBySomeCondition(x,new   PageRequest(0, 1));
A object = results.getContent.get(0);
```

Comment: Better to return `Slice<A>` (rather than `Page<A>`) because it doesn't add overhead for additional count query (see [Spring Data JPA doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Pageable` for that. The documentation schows different ways of using it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Comment: So I could use `Pageable`  with `@Query` and set the Page size to 1? will try it :-)

Comment: yeah, meanwhile @jackk provided an answer with code ;)